# Google Sheets Queries and 'not in'

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am trying to piece together a query that does a few things.  One, I want it to list out all the names in a column, and two, I only want it to list out the name from that column if it doesn't exist within an array of columns.

```
=QUERY(QUERY(Breakdown!$A$2:$B), "select Col1 where Col1 != '' and Col2 = 'Warrior' order by Col1 Asc")
```

I got as far as this, which displays all of the names in the column as I want it to, but when I start adding in 'not in' type parameters, I break it every which way.  How do I check that Col1 doesn't exist in the range `='Raid Comp'!A2:Q10`?

Here is the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X0GiOCAAve1CR4A3JG2Ybf-daMvrrhAsZF5V3XEdn4E/edit?usp=sharing

What I am tryin to do is once a name is entered within the colored areas, if name entered exists in the list below the colored area, the name is removed from the list.

Example:

[image]
[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: @player0 done, apologies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try regex in query:

```
=QUERY({Breakdown!$A$2:$B}, 
 "select Col1 
  where Col2 = 'Warrior' 
    and not Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 'Raid Comp'!A2:Q10)&"'  
  order by Col1 asc")
```

Comment: I was able to make it work with `=QUERY(QUERY(Breakdown!$A$2:$B), "select Col1 where Col1 != '' and Col2 = 'Warrior' and not Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 'Raid Comp'!A2:Q10)&"'order by Col1 Asc")`  If you edit your answer, I will mark it as the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm saying your initial formula is broken (Look at test sheet M14) and I've given you the formula I used to make it work (though it may not be perfect).  I'll mark your answer as an answer when its corrected.